# Split and join multiple logical "branches" of string data

Tags: c#, recursion

I know there's a couple similarly worded questions on SO about permutation listing, but they don't seem to be quite addressing really what I'm looking for.  I know there's a way to do this but I'm drawing a blank.  I have a flat file that resembles this format:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6
a|b,c,d|e|f|g,h|i
. . .
```

Now here's the trick: I want to create a list of all possible permutations of these rows, where a comma-separated list in the row represents possible values.  For example, I should be able to take an `IEnumerable<string>` representing the above to rows as such:

```
IEnumerable<string> row = new string[] { "a", "b,c,d", "e", "f", "g,h", "i" };
IEnumerable<string> permutations = GetPermutations(row, delimiter: "/");
```

This should generate the following collection of string data:

```
a/b/e/f/g/i
a/b/e/f/h/i
a/c/e/f/g/i
a/c/e/f/h/i
a/d/e/f/g/i
a/d/e/f/h/i
```

This to me seems like it would elegantly fit into a recursive method, but apparently I have a bad case of the Mondays and I can't quite wrap my brain around how to approach it.  Some help would be greatly appreciated.  What should `GetPermutations(IEnumerable<string>, string)` look like?

Comment: Hah no, I'm approaching 40, but thanks for asking.  No this is for an advertising application.  I am trying to read a config file for pages that specific ads will show up on.

Comment: Do you have any code or pseudo-code at hand?  Posting that may help get the answer you're trying to achieve.  I can think of a couple of ways to do it brute force, but haven't been able to refactor it into a recursive method (yet).

Comment: And out of curiousity, why `IEnumerable<string>`?  Wouldn't it be easier to do this with another type of collection and then cast to IEnumerable?

Comment: I think if I could figure out the pseudocode, the method would almost write itself.  My problem is I know what has to happen, but how to make it happen is eluding me.  I thought by recursing one level at a time, expanding the column to a collection of values, and then recursing on them would work, but I don't see how it can get away with not being aware of n-1 iterations, which defeats the recursion.  I think.

Comment: @Tim, I usually prefer working with `IEnumerable`, but I'm not married to it.  It's just usually easier for me to read, and if performance is not a serious consideration, I default to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really thought this would be a great recursive function, but I ended up not writing it that way.  Ultimately, this is the code I created:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPermutations(IEnumerable<string> possibleCombos, string delimiter)
{
    var permutations = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
    var comboArray = possibleCombos.ToArray();
    var splitCharArr = new char[] { ',' };

    permutations[0] = new List<string>();

    permutations[0].AddRange(
        possibleCombos
        .First()
        .Split(splitCharArr)
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Trim()))
        .Select(x => x.Trim()));

    for (int i = 1; i < comboArray.Length; i++)
    {
        permutations[i] = new List<string>();
        foreach (var permutation in permutations[i - 1])
        {
            permutations[i].AddRange(
                comboArray[i].Split(splitCharArr)
                .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Trim()))
                .Select(x => string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", permutation, delimiter, x.Trim()))
                );
        }
    }

    return permutations[permutations.Keys.Max()];
}
```

... my test conditions provided me with exactly the output I expected:

```
IEnumerable<string> row = new string[] { "a", "b,c,d", "e", "f", "g,h", "i" };
IEnumerable<string> permutations = GetPermutations(row, delimiter: "/");
foreach(var permutation in permutations)
{
    Debug.Print(permutation);
}
```

This produced the following output:

```
a/b/e/f/g/i
a/b/e/f/h/i
a/c/e/f/g/i
a/c/e/f/h/i
a/d/e/f/g/i
a/d/e/f/h/i
```

Thanks to everyone's suggestions, they really were helpful in sorting out what needed to be done in my mind.  I've upvoted all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is the most elegant approach, but it might get you started.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetPermutations(IEnumerable<string> row, 
                                                    string delimiter = "|")
{
    var separator = new[] { ',' };
    var permutations = new List<string>();
    foreach (var cell in row)
    {
        var parts = cell.Split(separator);
        var perms = permutations.ToArray();
        permutations.Clear();
        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            if (perms.Length == 0)
            {
                permutations.Add(part);
                continue;
            }
            foreach (var perm in perms)
            {
                permutations.Add(string.Concat(perm, delimiter, part));
            }
        }
    }
    return permutations;
}
```

Of course, if the order of the permutations is important, you can add an `.OrderBy()` at the end.

*Edit: added an alernative*

You could also build a list of string arrays, by calculating some numbers before determining the permutations.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetPermutations(IEnumerable<string> row, 
                                                    string delimiter = "|")
{
    var permutationGroups = row.Select(o => o.Split(new[] { ',' })).ToArray();
    var numberOfGroups = permutationGroups.Length;
    var numberOfPermutations = 
           permutationGroups.Aggregate(1, (current, pg) => current * pg.Length);
    var permutations = new List<string[]>(numberOfPermutations);

    for (var n = 0; n < numberOfPermutations; n++)
    {
        permutations.Add(new string[numberOfGroups]);
    }

    for (var position = 0; position < numberOfGroups; position++)
    {
        var permutationGroup = permutationGroups[position];
        var numberOfCharacters = permutationGroup.Length;
        var numberOfIterations = numberOfPermutations / numberOfCharacters;
        for (var c = 0; c < numberOfCharacters; c++)
        {
            var character = permutationGroup[c];
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++)
            {
                var index = c + (i * numberOfCharacters);
                permutations[index][position] = character;
            }
        }
    }

    return permutations.Select(p => string.Join(delimiter, p));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You had me at "recursive". Here's another suggestion:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetPermutations(string[] row, string delimiter,
                                            int colIndex = 0, string[] currentPerm = null)
{
    //First-time initialization:
    if (currentPerm == null) { currentPerm = new string[row.Length]; }

    var values = row[colIndex].Split(',');
    foreach (var val in values)
    {
        //Update the current permutation with this column's next possible value..
        currentPerm[colIndex] = val;

        //..and find values for the remaining columns..
        if (colIndex < (row.Length - 1))
        {
            foreach (var perm in GetPermutations(row, delimiter, colIndex + 1, currentPerm))
            {
                yield return perm;
            }
        }
        //..unless we've reached the last column, in which case we create a complete string:
        else
        {
            yield return string.Join(delimiter, currentPerm);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One algorithm you can use is basically like counting:

- Start with the 0th item in each list (00000)
- Increment the last value (00001, 00002 etc.)
- When you can't increas one value, reset it and increment the next (00009, 00010, 00011 etc.)
- When you can't increase any value, you're done.

Function:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Permutations(
    string input,
    char separator1, char separator2,
    string delimiter)
{
    var enumerators = input.Split(separator1)
        .Select(s => s.Split(separator2).GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    if (!enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext())) yield break;

    while (true)
    {
        yield return String.Join(delimiter, enumerators.Select(e => e.Current));
        if (enumerators.Reverse().All(e => {
                bool finished = !e.MoveNext();
                if (finished)
                {
                    e.Reset();
                    e.MoveNext();
                }
                return finished;
            }))
            yield break;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var perm in Permutations("a|b,c,d|e|f|g,h|i", '|', ',', "/"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(perm);
}
```